# Select all html including wrapper div

Tags: jquery

I am trying to select a div and its contents with jquery.

The div looks like this:

```
 <div class="fav-list" id="149656222">
  <ul>
    <li>hai</li>
    <li>hooy</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and my code

```
  alert($('#149656222').html());
```

this displays only this much:

```
<ul>
    <li>hai</li>
    <li>hooy</li>
  </ul>
```

And I need the entire div to be selected, what do I need to do for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use outerHTML

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/ghQHj/1/)**

```
alert($('#149656222')[0].outerHTML);
```

Or you can use jQuery to get the cross browser benifits

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/ghQHj/2/)**

```
alert($('<div></div>').append($('#149656222').clone()).html());
```